# ESP8266 Chip crash after some time

Tags: heap-memory, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I run a server in ESP8266  which accept argument and value when you click the submit button in the webpage. after some iteration of clicking the submit button, the esp8266 crashes with the Exception of:

```
--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------
Exception (29):
epc1=0x40205224 epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x00000000 depc=0x00000000

>>>stack>>>

ctx: cont
sp: 3ffffca0 end: 3fffffc0 offset: 0190
3ffffe30:  3fff1598 3fff1598 3ffffe80 4020521f  
3ffffe40:  3fff6354 3ffffe98 3ffffe80 40217ef0  
3ffffe50:  00000003 3ffffec0 3ffffe80 40217f20  
3ffffe60:  3ffffe98 3ffffea4 3fff1588 3fff0da4  
3ffffe70:  00000000 3ffffec0 00000005 402053a9  
3ffffe80:  3fff631c 0029002f 00003a30 3fff6300  
3ffffe90:  0029002f 800001da 3fff6354 0029002f  
3ffffea0:  00000001 3fffbf5c 0005002f 00217d42  
3ffffeb0:  00000001 3fff0dac 3ffffefc 4020cb24  
3ffffec0:  3fff68b4 01da01df 00000000 fffffffe  
3ffffed0:  00000000 3fffc6fc 00000000 3fff1c88  
3ffffee0:  00000000 3fffdad0 40223278 00000000  
3ffffef0:  3ffffefc 3fffff64 3fff0a00 40223428  
3fffff00:  00000000 000003e8 3fffff60 03e87701  
3fffff10:  402583d1 00000004 3fff0d58 4020171a  
3fffff20:  40258677 00000004 3fff0d58 3fff0d5c  
3fffff30:  00000000 4bc6a7f0 0189374b 00000000  
3fffff40:  00000000 00000000 4bc6a7f0 00000000  
3fffff50:  000e001a 00050008 4010051c 0001fc51  
3fffff60:  00000000 6c80e048 4024c800 3ffe8514  
3fffff70:  024bbda9 80000000 00000000 4010059d  
3fffff80:  00000000 00000000 00000001 3fff1cc8  
3fffff90:  3fffdad0 00000000 0001fc51 40211f35  
3fffffa0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3fff1c88 40218fd4  
3fffffb0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffe899c 40100f45  
<<<stack<<<

last failed alloc call: 4020521F(100)

--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)
```

For debugging: Free Heap is printed(runs every 2 seconds using millis) in the serial monitor by

```
 Serial.println(ESP.getFreeHeap());
```

[image]

The submit button is sending the following argument and value(Partial only) :

```
http://192.168.4.1?user=1234&password=1234&data1=qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm&data1=qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm&data2=qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm&data3=qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm&data4=qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
```

as you can see the FreeHeap is going down until it reaches the minimum where ESP8266 can't handle.

[image]

Is there a way to refresh or reuse the heap without rebooting the Chip?

Is safeString can help to this problem ?

Comment: use the stack decoder IDE plugin

Comment: "Is there a way to refresh or reuse the heap without rebooting" - no, you need to find the memory leak. The exception decoder won't be of much help here I suspect. The program will crash as soon as the memory is exhausted and that won't necessarily be at the exact same place with every occurrence. You will want to start removing/re-adding code to find out which section is responsible for the leak.

Comment: `Is there a way to refresh or reuse the heap without rebooting the Chip?`, the best way is not to use Heap, in Arduino, that's almost means don't use `String` unless you fully understand it.

Comment: Read https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/75758/40646